# Passing an component state down the tree and to trigger top level rerender inside useEffect()

Tags: reactjs

First new to ReactJS so bear with me.  I have an app that I am attempting to sync using an external api. The structure looks something like

```
APP  ----> NAVBAR ---->MENU
       |            |->AVATAR 
       |
       ->MAIN -> HOME
              |->PROFILE --->PROFILE
                          |->LOGINHANDLER
```

The loginhandler authenticates with the api server and obtains credentials which the profile compenent then uses to call an update and retrieve the users profile from the api server.  The NAVBAR has the AVATAR which uses an image retrieved from the profile.

If the profile updater  gets an updated image I need to trigger state update in the navbar to use the new profile image

```js
    function App() {
    const loggedIn = (localStorage.getItem('wp_user') !== null);
    const [seed,setSeed] = useState(0)
    const update =()=>{
        setSeed(Math.random);
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Navigation auth={loggedIn} />
            <Main onChange={update}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I know that using this is rerendering the whole app...which is not ideal.
Anyway I then pass the function down through each compontent via props until I hit the Profile component

```js
export default function Profile(onChange){
    const [name,setName] = useState(getUserName())
    const [email,setEmail] =useState('');
    const [link,setLink] =useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        new Api().getProfile().then(res=>{
            let update = false;
            if(res === null || res === undefined){
            } else {
                if (res.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
                    if (res['name'] !== name){
                        setName(res['name']);
                    }
                }
                if(res.hasOwnProperty('first_name')){
                    let fName = res['first_name'];
                    let sName = res['last_name'];
                    let updated = fName + " "+ sName;
                    if(updated !== name){
                        setName(updated);
                    }
                }
                if (res.hasOwnProperty('email')) {
                    if (res['email'] !== email){
                        setEmail(res['email']);
                    }
                }
                if (res.hasOwnProperty('link')) {
                    if (res['link'] !== link){
                        setLink(res['link']);
                    }
                }
                if (res.hasOwnProperty('avatar_urls')) {
                    if(getProfileUrl() !== res.avatar_urls['96']) {
                        setProfileUrl(res.avatar_urls['96'])
                        update = true;
                    }
                }
                if(update){
                    onChange();
                }
            }
        });
    }, [onChange]);
    return (
        <Card>
            <Typography component='a'  href={link} >
                Name: {name}
            </Typography>
            <Typography>
                Email: {email}
            </Typography>
        </Card>
    )

}
```

I have used profile like

```js
  function UserWindow(onChange){
    return (
        <div>
            <header className="Login-Header">
                <h1>Profile</h1>
            </header>
            <Profile onChange={onChange}/>
            <AuthenticatorForm/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and the Main window looks like

```js
const Main = ({onChange}) => {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}></Route>
            <Route path='/User' element={<UserWindow onChange={onChange} />}></Route>
        </Routes>
    </div>
)}
```

I am getting the error...

> `ERROR onChange is not a function TypeError: onChange is not a function`

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L9r9.png

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to de-structure the props in your `UserWindow` component like you did in `Main`. The parameter you define when you create a function component is the `props` object, so by saying `{onChange}` you are basically getting the `onChange` prop from the props object in a new variable.

If you instead just use `onChange`, you are basically naming your props object `onChange`. Here is a solution:

```
function UserWindow({onChange}){ // <-- here
    return (
        <div>
            <header className="Login-Header">
                <h1>Profile</h1>
            </header>
            <Profile onChange={onChange}/>
            <AuthenticatorForm/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This was my issue I didnt destructure props correctly...

Answer (score 1):

You've got a bunch of syntax errors to check through. hint there is to look at the props you've forgottne to destructure (onChange) => ({ onChange })

But I would highly recommend learning about context providers for passing state around different components, your approach will get complicated quickly.

old doc - https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html

new doc - https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext

Comment: Thanks Daniel absolutlely helpful ...I wish you could declare 2 answers correct

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/21122267/danielricado I have worked on the APP i have  a follow up -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/78071249?noredirect=1